# Understanding in-memory databases

Tags: redis, memcached, in-memory-database

I am new to this field of studies and I want to know if I understood everything right.

In Memory database management systems (like Redis and memcached) are for just keeping data as in cache to access quicker. I mean everything is done manually: you read from database then write in cache and next time read from cache. The only task that redis/Memcached do, is they remove records after some time and manage task queues? Am I right?

Comment: Redis isn't in-memory

Answer (score 0):

That may be the primary use case for redis/memcached, but not for the broader category of in-memory database systems.

Many (most, for my company) use cases don't involve another DBMS; the in-memory database system (IMDS) is the only database management system.

Further, there are IMDS that resemble persistent DBMS (HANA, TimesTen, VoltDB, eXtremeDB and others). They can be embedded or client/server, SQL or NoSQL, offer high availability, clustering, sharding and much more.